# Tilestache return empty geojson

Tags: postgis, geojson, tilestache

I have successfully installed tilestache. I also has succesfully add a layer using shapefile from [here](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons). But when I tried to use [my own shapefile](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?sdfka6c0in0cac8), the server always return empty featurecollection. I have tried to add `ST_Transform()` in the query but still return empty feature.

My config file:

```
{
  "cache":
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "path": "/tmp/stache",
    "umask": "0000"
  },
  "layers":
  {
        "osm-processed_p1": {
            "allowed origin": "*",
            "provider": {
                "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:Provider",
                "kwargs": {
                    "dbinfo": {
                        "host": "127.0.0.1",
                        "user": "postgres",
                        "database": "ts_data"
                    },
                    "queries": [
                        "SELECT gid, geom AS __geometry__ FROM osm.kalimantan"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?